# Global variable gets different values when used in different static methods

Tags: c++, class, global-variables, static-methods, static-members

I have the following class that implements static methods that must use a **single** global array. It is defined as such:

```
//Defined in LockTrack.h file

enum LOCK_ID{
    LOCKID_0,
    LOCKID_1,
    LOCKID_2,

    LOCKID_COUNT
};

static LOCK_ID __glob_lock_ids[LOCKID_COUNT];


class CLockTrack
{
public:
    static void getLockedLocks(/*parameters*/)
    {
        //__glob_lock_ids = points to 0x015ef558 address in memory
        LOCK_ID lockID = __glob_lock_ids[0];
    }

    static void inline setLock(LOCK_ID lockID)
    {
        //__glob_lock_ids = points to 0x015ef330 address in memory
        __glob_lock_ids[lockID] = LOCK_ON_FLAG;
    }
};
```

But what happens is that the '__glob_lock_ids' pointer points to different memory locations in each method. Why? And how to fix this?

Comment: Are you _really_ defining a static variable in a header file? What behavior do you expect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, that's not a global. Change it to

```
extern LOCK_ID __glob_lock_ids[LOCKID_COUNT];
```

and move

```
LOCK_ID __glob_lock_ids[LOCKID_COUNT];
```

into a single implementation file. Your version, `static`, will effectively create a new variable for each translation unit that includes the header.

Comment: It's all in one .h file. Where do I need to move it to?

Comment: @user843732 to an implementation file (`.cpp` file)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I don't have a .cpp file for it. Any way to do this in the .h file?

Comment: @user843732 you can move it to any implementation file. You surely must have at least one.

Comment: @user843732: What keeps you from creating the file ?

Comment: OK, I created the LockTrack.cpp and put the LOCK_ID declaration there. But now when I compile the project I get, "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "enum LOCK_ID * __glob_lock_ids" (?__glob_lock_ids@@3PAW4LOCK_ID@@A)"

Comment: You put the line `LOCK_ID __glob_lock_ids[LOCKID_COUNT];` in the cpp file, that's it. This is a definition. You don't put the enum declaration in the cpp file.

Comment: No, the enum is in the .h file. I did it exactly as you said.

Comment: @user843732 is the cpp file getting compiled?

Comment: I'm assuming so. I guess I need to add that I have several projects including this "LockTrack.h" that are parts of one solution. One compiles OK but the rest started giving me this linker error (that I quoted above.)

Comment: @user843732 don't assume. Never assume. If you have several projects that include "LockTrack.h", you need to link against the library generated. How you do that depends on platform and compiler and is a very broad topic. But the main thing here is that for a global you **don't** use `static`, because then it's not global (as you clearly saw in your code).

Comment: OK, I fixed it. Thanks for your help. I am using Visual Studio 2008. What solved it is that besides simply including my .h file I need to do "Add Existing Item" on it and .cpp files from the VS menu for each project that uses that .h file.

Comment: @user843732 nope. That appears to work, but it's still not a shared global between projects. Now every project will have its own copy of that variable. To have a global throught all projects, it must only be defined in one and linked against that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "linked against that"?